# What does the phrase “to divide a bill” mean (in politics)?

Tags: terminology

Please explain what does the phrase “to divide a bill” mean in politics?

Comment: Politics where??

Comment: You are right. It depends. ) If I can, I’ll find out. (The question was asked by another person on a forum without specifying the country).

Comment: Great Britain, Parliament: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Congressional_Globe/OksuAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22divide+the+bill%22&pg=PA4341&printsec=frontcover

Answer (score 2):

A bill in politics is a proposal for a set of laws. Those voting on the bill might argue that some of the proposals in the bill are good and that some are bad, so they would be happy to vote for the bill if the bad laws were removed. That is, split the bill into two or more bills.

I'm in Australia, and there's a particular political tactic here (and probably elsewhere) of proposing a bill on some popular laws (that even the opposition will feel pressured to vote in favor of), but to also include other laws in the bill that are more controversial, as a way of slipping them through the system. There is often a demand to "split the bill" so that the various laws can be voted on separately.

Comment: This sounds plausible to me for the UK and/Australia, for example.